# Doctrine 2: How to enter a length greater than 24 hours into a "time" field

Tags: datetime, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have a database of audiobooks. Some of those books are longer in length than 24 hours. I am having difficulty creating a doctrine entity that will map a `length` property longer than 24 hours because a `time` field accepts a `DateTime` object and any time over 24 hours is added onto the next day so 33 hrs becomes 9 hrs.

```
<?php

namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Audiobook
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime $length
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="length", type="time")
     */
     protected $length;
```

Any idea how to make this work? I'm also using Symfony2.

Comment: Store length as an integer (in minutes or seconds). Then convert to h:m:s.

Comment: Yes I ended up doing that. I tried not to but after attempting to "go against the grain" for sometime I now see that the PHP DateTime class is simply not designed to work with time in this way, it's designed to work with *date* times. Better to measure intervals like these in seconds or minutes. Perhaps it might be possible to create a custom Doctrine type using DateInterval. If someone makes it I would like to see it!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are actually looking for [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/class.dateinterval) instead of [`DateTime`](http://php.net/class.datetime), because the later one represents a moment in time, which "length" can't be.

This said there is no mapping from `DateInterval` to a SQL-type (yet?) and even I am not aware of any interval-like SQL-type at all. what you can do is to create an own type, that maps `DateInterval` on a `VARCHAR` of the format [`PT28H`](http://php.net/dateinterval.construct)